# Need help creating SQL Server datasource for JBoss EAP 6.1.0

Tags: java, sql-server, jboss

I am working on a web service application on JBoss EAP 6.1.0, which requires a datasource for SQL Server 2008 to be created. I have downloaded and extracted the sqljdbc jar file, but am not sure where it goes on the application server. I tried referencing the EAP 6.1 configuration guide and a couple of other websites, but that did not help. I would be very grateful if someone could guide me with the steps to register the datasource on the application server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It goes into your modules folder. You have have something like the following:

```
<JBOSS_HOME>\modules\com\microsoft\sqlserver\main
```

Your sqljdbc would be inside the folder structure above. You would also need to create a module.xml file in the same folder similar to:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.microsoft.sqlserver">
 <resources>
    <resource-root path="sqljdbc4.jar"/>
 </resources>
 <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
 </dependencies>
</module>
```

Then finally in your standalone.xml, the datasources section should have a drivers definition that references your module as such:

```
<drivers>
  <driver name="sqlserver" module="com.microsoft.sqlserver">
    <xa-datasource-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
  </driver>
</drivers>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you very much, that was very helpful. I was able to register a sample datasource in my localhost, and I am able to see it reflected on the localhost console.

Comment: I tried to test the datasource as follows: 
/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=java\:jboss\/datasources\/TestDS:test-connection-in-pool (The datasource created is java:jboss/datasources/TestDS)

The following is the output of the command:
{"outcome" => "failed","failure-description" => "JBAS014807: Management resource '[(\"subsystem\" => \"datasources\"),(\"xa-data-source\" => \"java:jboss/datasources/TestDS\")]' not found","rolled-back" => true}

What could be the issue?

Comment: Glad that helped, if you are happy with the answer to have resolved your datasource creation issue, please accept as the correct answer.

Comment: Try the command as `/subsystem=datasources/data-source=TestDS:test-connection-in-pool`